# z-index not working in Wordpress theme for drop-down menu

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, z-index, buddypress

I'm developing a child theme for the Buddypress default theme.  I have customised the look of the navigation bar quite a lot, and now I am trying to get drop-down menus working.  They work fine in the default theme.  In the default theme a class is added to list items in the nav bar that are hovered over, .sfhover, and this div class has the CSS 'position:relative;z-index:1000'.  The #container div that the drop-down menus should stay on top of has the CSS 'position:relative' and no z-index set.  Presumably this means that the z-index is the default of 0.  Finally the #header div which includes the nav bar has the CSS 'position:relative;z-index:1000'.

I have checked that in my child theme all of the CSS is the same for these three divs, and indeed it is, and yet the drop-down menu does not show above the #container div, but is cut off where the #container div starts.

You can see what I mean if you visit [this page](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/), and hover over the 'links' items in the nav bar.  You will need the following credentials to see the page as it is password protected:

Username: guest
Password: stackoverflow

Perhaps someone can spot why this isn't working as expected with my child theme?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with your z-index. You have the `#header` set to `overflow: hidden` which means that nothing will flow out of it your nav sub menu included. Remove this and you will be good.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect the overflow:hidden to effect the sub menus as they are within the #header div, but removing that did indeed fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

problem is in `<div id="header">` block which has property `overflow: hidden` and it hides everything that out of it dimension. You have to remove it and if you use it for clear floats, try another method: boilerplate clearfix or just add div with `clear:both` after `<div id="header">`